# How to see total uptime on a mac

Tags: terminal, ssd, hdd

Back when I had a Windows machine I used a program called CrystalDiskInfo to see total hours of operation of my computer. I only used the numbers for fun or to like indicate how "used" my PC was..

So I'm looking for a terminal command or an app that can display that information for me.

Screenshot of the crystaldiskinfo gui.
[image]

Comment: Sidenote, the crystaldiskinfo does work in apple bootcamp. But I do not have that atm.

Comment: Your title is asking for the uptime of your Mac, but the utility screen shot you're showing is showing you the "power on hours" of a disk drive, not the uptime of your OS over reboots. Is what you really want the power on hours of a drive in your Mac?

Answer (score 2):

The command you want is called [uptime](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/uptime.1.html):

```
|ruby-2.1.2| cortana in ~
○ → uptime
14:49  up 3 days, 21:51, 4 users, load averages: 1.41 1.32 1.30
```

From the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/uptime.1.html):

> The uptime utility displays the current time, the length of time the system has been up, the number of users, and the load average of the system over the last 1, 5, and 15 minutes.

Comment: This is a for session. I want the total uptime (from when the mac was booted the first time).

Comment: I have found this post. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70425/is-there-a-utility-for-mac-that-shows-the-information-of-an-ssd-like-the-health?rq=1 
Mike answers that a terminal based program called smartools does the job, and I can see it does it well for him. But I just tried and didnt have any luck. I have installed smartools in terminal, but it doesnt want to load the information.

Comment: @JW_ that utility you're using on Windows is reporting the power on hours of a *hard drive* in your machine, not the *power on hours* of the machine itself. Nothing, in any OS, I've ever encountered tracks uptime over reboots for a system. Your question should be rephrased to "How do I see the power on time of a hard drive in my OS X machine?" if that's what you're truly after.