# Check whether a MacBook is new or not

Tags: macbook-pro

I have bought a new MacBook Pro 13, 2015.

How can I check whether it is a new or used one? I don't mean optical checks. Maybe some kind of system values, etc.

Comment: Installed macOS version, timestamp of key system directories, package it came in, trustworthiness of vendor etc, there might be a lot of indicators

Comment: @patrix it was some not actual OS and I have updated it after first start. I don't know which one it was.

Comment: @patrix the rest of your comment - I don't know how to check it :) thats why this question

Comment: Perhaps filling in the serial on the [Apple warranty site](https://checkcoverage.apple.com)  can give you sufficient information to determine if it's new? I don't have my mac with me to check what information is provided on that site.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke - I have checked it on this site. This information is ok - 1 year after the first day I have used it.

Comment: @MikroDel If you have updated it already it will be rather difficult to check. The timestamp of `/var/db/.AppleSetupDone` might give a clue.

Comment: @patrix I have started terminal paste "/var/db/.AppleSetupDone" and got "permission denied"

Comment: "/var/log/cups/error_log" show last change some months before I have got it. Does it mean anything?

Comment: And also under software some utility for fax and scanner are changed in 2015. Or maybe its simply the date the software were changed

Comment: Try `ls -l /var/db/.AppleSetupDone`. The CUPS error log gets installed empty on a major upgrade, so if has older entries it might be a clue.

Comment: "ls -l /var/db/.AppleSetupDone" this shows me the first day I have used it

Comment: "/var/log/cups/error_log" has size of 0

Comment: What makes you doubt that it's new? Was it not bought in original sealed packaging?

Comment: @barbecue it was interesting for me whether its generally possible or not. And how to check it. It was original sealed. Other way Im not an expert in the question original sealed or not :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The only thing I can think of that cannot be tricked by an Erase and Install of the OS is the cycle count on the battery, provided it's the original battery. Essentially this number tells you how many times the battery has been depleted and recharged.

**Cycle count of the battery:**
Click the Apple menu and then 'About this Mac > System Report... > Hardware > Power' and look for "Cycle Count" under 'Battery Information > Health Information'

The lower the number the better. Now there is a chance that the reseller you bought it off of replaced the battery, but it's highly unlikely. It's a lot of work to remove and reinstall a battery in these models (see the full [34 steps here](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Early+2015+Battery+Replacement/45137)) so unless the battery is faulty or nearing the end of its life cycle, it just wouldn't make sense to replace it.

You could also call Apple Support and ask if the serial number of that machine has been previously registered under a name other than yours. **They cannot tell you the previous name or any other information on the account** if it has been registered before (due to privacy laws), but I don't see why they couldn't just let you know if the machine has already been registered with them in the past.

Comment: cycle count = 1

Comment: Its not possible to trick the system to show any number under cycle count without battery replacement?

Comment: I have called apple support and they told me this serial number was not used earlier and the first time was the date I have become it.

Comment: @MikroDel No, it is not possible to trick the system to show the incorrect number under the battery cycle count. The only way to change this number is to replace the battery.

Comment: @NYKg, what makes you so sure that it's not possible to spoof the number? (Genuine question.) I don't doubt that the battery cycle count is generally a very good indicator of a MacBook's usage. But I wouldn't be sure that the counter couldn't be overwritten with some trickery.

Comment: @Emil Fair question. When I worked for Apple this is actually a question I asked an engineer when I had to escalate a particularly difficult case and I was told at that time that it was not possible. My mind has also wandered and sometimes I think maybe there is a human out there smart enough to figure out how to write a script or execute something in Terminal to change that number, but it would be software-based (for lack of better terms). After an E&I (which is usually done before or after a resell) it would revert back to its natural state.

Comment: @Emil: Modern high-performance re-chargeable batteries have their own microcontroller with their own OS. The battery *itself* is doing the counting, macOS just gets the data from the battery. Now, it *could* be possible to hack the microcontroller on the battery, but I highly doubt that.

Comment: The SMART counters on the hard drive can't be reset either, but I don't know what the numbers for a new system would look like.

Comment: @NYKg what does "E&I" mean?

Comment: @MikroDel My apologies, it means 'Erase and Install'. It's where you erase your Macintosh HD (usually after backing it up) and reinstall the operating system from the Recovery Partition instead of simply reinstalling the operating system from the App Store.

Comment: @NYKg thanks! And if I use my macbook, after cycle count number = 3 I will return it to the store. It will be sold again. Will the next person become the information (via support hotline) that this notebook was already sold January 2017?

Comment: Apple states that 3 or 4 battery cycles can be normal on a new Mac, anything above that would be questionable. The first time the new owner calls Apple Support they may be informed that it was previously registered and asked to re-register it, but as my original answer states Apple advisors cannot give them ANY of your information.

Comment: @NYKg is it suspicious that my battery was manufactured November 2016? I have checked it with "Battery Health 2". The MBP 13, 2015 is from early 2015. And battery is from late 2016.

Comment: @NYKg I have asked it as a question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/269953/mbp-13-early-2015-but-battery-was-manufactured-at-november-2016-why

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the hard drive. The SMART statu should have lots on informations.

Here is how to look at it:

[Is there a utility for mac that shows the information of an SSD like the health etc…?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70425/is-there-a-utility-for-mac-that-shows-the-information-of-an-ssd-like-the-health)

A samble output from my computer:

```
0x01  0x008  4           17080  ---  Lifetime Power-On Resets
0x01  0x010  4           13034  ---  Power-on Hours
0x01  0x018  6     71009610622  ---  Logical Sectors Written
0x01  0x020  6       689785468  ---  Number of Write Commands
0x01  0x028  6     96669153261  ---  Logical Sectors Read
0x01  0x030  6      1474232041  ---  Number of Read Commands
```

It's even less likely they would have replaced the hard drive than the battery :)

Comment: There is no way to check it without some apps you should buy or trials? With onboard tools its not possible?

Comment: @MikroDel [smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download#InstalltheOSXDarwinpackage) is free and has a low footprint (>500 kb)

Comment: Yep. Read the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to look in the Library/Receipts folder; this will show you
a lot of installations/updates, with dates, and gives a good indication of usage
that isn't tied to any user (the user info can be easily removed).  That seems to
work for older OS X (10.9).

On recent OS releases, the Receipts folders are deprecated; instead of looking
for install/update traces there, open System Information, and look at Software/Installations for a listing of installed patches/updates etc., with dates.   In the last six years, keeping my system updated has logged hundreds
of entries there.

Comment: I have found "Library" but I have not found "Receipts"

Comment: It might depend on the OS version; I find both /System/Library/Receipts having recent dates, and /Library/Receipts with older dates (back to 10.5).

Comment: I have 10.12.2 OS

Comment: The problem here would be if the nefarious seller did a fresh install of macOS, which is quite easy to do, the folder you mention would be empty.

Comment: @Allan: yes, but that would give an indication (it would be missing, presumably, the factory test CPU_AHT entry).