# MBP 13 early 2015, but battery was manufactured at November 2016. Why?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

Is it suspicious that my battery was manufactured November 2016? I have checked it with "Battery Health 2". The MBP 13, 2015 is from early 2015. And battery is from late 2016.

*Update*

I have started with this question: [Check whether a MacBook is new or not](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/269606/check-whether-a-macbook-is-new-or-not)

I didn't want to ask other questions in comment, that's why I've created this one.

*Update 2*

This is the information I've got with serial number:

Model:  - MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)

Codename:   - No codename assigned.

Build Country:  - This unit was built in China.

Build Year: - We could not verify the build year of this unit.

Build Week  - Week 24 (June) or week 51 (December).

Production Nr.: - This unit was number 333 to be built that week.

Comment: 2015 is the model design year, not the manufacture year. It is possible for a 2015 model type to be built a long time after it was initially designed.

Comment: @JohnKeates I thought that at the moment (Jan 2017) apple produce in MBP row only 2016 and late 2015

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I do not believe this is suspicious. The early-2015 model 13" MBP is still a current model. So, unless you actually bought the MBP **before** November 2016, this is not at all suspicious.

To put your mind at ease you can check your MBP's serial number at a number of sites to retrieve the manufacturing date amongst other info. You can access one such site [here](http://www.appleserialnumberinfo.com/).

[EDIT]

In response to question update.

The fact your serial number search shows it was built in either Week 24 (June) or week 51 (December) backs up my assertion. This is a new MBP built in December 2016 (**after** the manufacture of your battery and **before** you purchased it).

**This confirms there is absolutely nothing suspicious about your MBP.**

Comment: I have checked the serial number. See my update of the question.

Comment: I have become it new january 2017. What is the explanation that the early 2015 one has a battery from november 2016? Or the 2015 row is still in production?

Comment: Yes, as I said in my answer, the early-2015 model 13" MBP is still a current model. If you checked your MBP serial number I'm guessing the manufacture date was probably November or December 2016?

Comment: I have updated my question with the information I have got via your link with my serial number.